# How to generate a new Csrf-Token for a Form

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, csrf

i got a Form. When i change a Select-Element inside that Form, i do an Ajax-Call to the same URL, which basically loads a new Form that has some additional Fields or has some Fields removed (different Categories, different Fields...).

Now, the Form i get from the Request obviously will have the SAME Csrf-Token, since the Token lives for one Request. Meaning, i will have to generate a new token, whenever i do this kind of action, but i have seriously no idea on how to do this.

My assumption is that i have to do something like

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $form->get('csrf')    ->regenerateCsrfToken()
}
```

But obviously that function doesn't exist, but it should be something alike those lines. Any input will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $form->get('csrf')->getCsrfValidator()->getHash(true);
}
```

`getHash(true)` will regenerate the hash, and store the changed hash in the generator, so your form will retrieve the new value when you retrieve it from the element later.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @MichaelGooden is absolutely correct. That's the general approach to the problem. However in what I've done there's another error inside, that may be relevant for other users, too. My for the `select.onChange()` method is:

- save form data
- get new form (GET /item/add/categoryId)
- repopulate identical form fields

Doing this, i was accidentally saving the CSRF-Token, too and re-populated the stored token as the new one. Obviously that couldn't work. So in my `form.rePopulate(data)` function i simply excluded the CSRF-Element and that's it, all working like a charm.